# Progress bar for file upload using JQuery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I want to implement a progress bar for file upload. I searched a lot and found many of them to be complex. I needed to do a class assignment only and so require to implement the progress bar using jQuery UI. I'm not able to get how to implement this and how to find the file upload status percentage. I see lot of similar questions in SO but they all use some kind of packages  which we need to use directly, but I've to use only jQuery or jQuery UI but not ready made packages.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: What server side language are you using for uploads? I think in the end you will realize good upload progress bars are indeed "complex" so I suggest you to find a package and work with that.

Comment: @jtheman, I only want to do class assignment and hence wanted it to be simple. I plan to use PHP on server side, though there is no restriction as such.

Answer (score 2):

fine uploader http://fineuploader.com/ will provide you with a cross browser compatible way to deal with uploads as well as an API that includes a way to create a progress bar.